# Activity without UI to write a maintainable code

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the use of Activity without UI? I have a MainActivity where I feel the code is too long and I was thinking about possibly creating a separate Activity without UI for each task and call it in my Main Activity (or use a Headless Fragment maybe?) in order to keep my code maintainable. Is that a bad approach? How do you manage relatively long code in one Activity?

Comment: "How do you manage relatively long code in one Activity?" -- move pieces of it out into separate non-`Activity` classes, generally. There has been quite a bit written about GUI architectures applied to Android (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you please point me out to a good source? I'm familiar with inner/anonymous/nested classes, and separate classes with setters/getters. But I could use more information on how to use separate classes for more complicated operations. Like for one of the tasks that I have I need to create an intent of MediaRecorder and an object of MediaPlayer and then do some lightweight comparison on audio files. And there're a few similar tasks in length to this one in the same activity.

Comment: "some lightweight comparison on audio files" -- this would appear to have nothing particular to do with an activity. So, move that out into some separate Java class, probably just inheriting from `Object` (i.e., no `extends` keyword on the class declaration). An activity might create an instance of that object and call methods on it, but the code itself would reside elsewhere. IOW, you do the same thing for "complex operations" as you would do for not-so-complex operations, in general.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for taking the time to clarify this. Most useful answer to be honest.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can I include user-permission methods in the separate class or is that a bad practice?

Comment: Not sure what "user-permission methods" means. If you mean working with runtime permissions... `checkSelfPermission()` can be used elsewhere, though it needs a `Context` to do so. `requestPermissions()` runs through an `Activity` or `Fragment`, and the response goes to that same `Activity` or `Fragment`. Hence, working with runtime permissions usually is handled by the `Activity` or `Fragment`. The work that *needs* the runtime permissions, though could be broken out into a separate class, so long as it is triggered only from the activity/fragment when you know that you have permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bad idea.  It makes sense to break an activity up into multiple classes if its too large/too complicated.  If those pieces have a UI, that's basically a fragment.  If they don't, they should be some other class.  But there's no reason to make them Activities-  they're just classes.

THere's very few places where it makes sense to have a headless Activity.  Almost all of those places are where Android requires you to start a context but you're not sure which one to start up yet (for example a headless activity that does url routing that's too complex to put into the manifest).

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of things wrong with your questions.

First... An Activity without UI, then doestn need to be an Activity.

Second, you must know what is a class and why we use classs.

Third, When you have long code, maybe your logic is bad, you can separate en in other class the code, example: Adapters, Helpers, Task, etc.... the same activity and code must give you and idea how separte correctly if you know the concepts, please, maybe if you post the code we can help you more.